# HTTP get request communication js to PHP doesn't return a result?

Tags: php, javascript, html, http, communication

So I have a little js program running in a HTML5 canvas and I have a little http get request function in my js. The function itsself works(tested it with quite a few examples on the internet and it worked), but my own webserver doesnt return the right stuff when a request is sent to it.

my PHP looks like this:

> ```
> <?php echo VVV::getUser()->userID ?>
> ```

When I open it in my browser it returns me the correct values the getUser()->userID returns. However when I send a Http request from my js it gets an empty result, however it works when used on various testing pages in the internet, so it must be my PHP or my server that cause this problem. any ideas?

Comment: What does the debug console in your browser show?

Comment: Maybe I have an old browser, but my browser doesnt have a debug console of itself.

Comment: What browser are you using? could this be a cross-domain issue? how are you doing the request in the javascript? can you share more code?

Comment: Could be cross-domain, I suspected that too. The request is a function in a little engine I got from someone, I don't think I'd find the function in the engine. If it was cross domain, how would I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a cross-domain AJAX request problem. To solve this you really have just two options:

- Have PHP make the cross-domain request. So whatever site that uses your AJAX will make a request to it's own server (like to its own ajax.php script) which then makes a request to your server and then returns it to the client.
- Try to use something like [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) JavaScript library for cross-domain AJAX requests and see if that helps.

Comment: How would the first one work exactly? You mean I'd have like a ajax.php on my server, then my js requests that and the ajax.php requests another php file and sends its results back to my js?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little sample for a simple cross-domain request (JSONP style):

1) On your server side, change the response to something like:

```
<?php echo( 'callbackFunc(' . VVV::getUser()->userID . ');' ) ?>
```

2) On the client side do something like:

```
function callbackFunc( userId )
{
    // Do something with the userId
}

// Create a script tag which will load the call to the callback function
// with the user ID generated by the PHP code.

var s = document.createElement( "SCRIPT" );
s.src = "http://yourserver/yourpath/yourscript.php?maybesome=params";
document.body.appendChild( s );
```

The code loaded from your server will call callbackFunc() with the user ID.